# apache, php-fpm and mod_fcgid - unable to write to file

Tags: apache-httpd, php, alma-linux

I have install apache, php-fpm and mod_fcgid, and trying to write to file.

I have created PHP pools, here's the config files:

```
[test.internal.innovisage.com]

...

user = test
group = test

...

listen.owner = test
listen.group = test

...

listen = /run/php-fpm/test.internal.innovisage.com.sock
```

Here's my Apache configuration file:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/test.internal.innovisage.com/public_html>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<virtualhost *:80>
ServerName test.internal.innovisage.com
ServerAlias test.internal.innovisage.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/test.internal.innovisage.com/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/test.internal.innovisage.com-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/test.internal.innovisage.com-access.log combined
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
         Options +ExecCGI
         FcgidConnectTimeout 20
         AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
         AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
         Alias /php7-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi
         ProxyPassMatch " ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/run/php-fpm/example.com.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/example.com/public_html/"
     </IfModule>
</virtualhost>
```

Here's the list of pools:

```
[root@almalinux-8 test]# ps aux | grep test.intern
test        2814  0.0  0.3 425492 12344 ?        S    18:06   0:00 php-fpm: pool test.internal.innovisage.com
test        2815  0.0  0.3 425492 12344 ?        S    18:06   0:00 php-fpm: pool test.internal.innovisage.com
test        2816  0.0  0.3 425492 12344 ?        S    18:06   0:00 php-fpm: pool test.internal.innovisage.com
test        2817  0.0  0.3 425492 12344 ?        S    18:06   0:00 php-fpm: pool test.internal.innovisage.com
test        2818  0.0  0.3 425492 12344 ?        S    18:06   0:00 php-fpm: pool test.internal.innovisage.com
```

It says the script owner is test.

```
<?php
echo "<p>Current User ID: ".getmyuid()."</p>";
echo "<p>Current Script Owner: ".get_current_user()."</p>";
phpinfo();
?>
```

[image]

When running the script as *test* user from command line, it writes to file. However, when running from the web browser, it does not create the file.

Is there anything else I need to change to get the script to write to file?

Answer (score 0):

I missed modifying this line here.

> ProxyPassMatch " ^/(.*.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/run/php-fpm/example.com.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/html/example.com/public_html/"

Replaced it with the correct domain and I can now write files to all permitted locations.

> ProxyPassMatch " ^/(.*.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/run/php-fpm/test.internal.innovisage.com.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/test.internal.innovisage.com/public_html/"